# Never ending select with troublesome inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Query is (short version):

```
SELECT TOP (2000) *
  FROM [...].[Documents] AS [D] 
        INNER JOIN dbo.SE_CMSClientMatters AS [mat]  ON [mat].[Mcode] = [D].[custom2]
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me why it does not work -i.e. never completes execution - ran for 13 hours and still no sign of completing.

Documents table has around 12 million rows, ClientMatters has around 330,000 rows.

The original query has several other left joins and this is the only inner join. If I leave it out, the query completes in 20 seconds!

Its 4am so either I'm losing it or have missed something obvious. PS - I did rebuild the indexes. The Custom2 field is part of a group of fields indexed (see image).

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the issues I see is

- `mat.MCode` is of type `varchar(27)`
- `D.custom2` is of type `nvarchar(32)`

This is **horrible** (performance-wise) when joining - one column is Unicode, the other is not.

Try to cast one to the other - something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (2000) *
FROM [...].[Documents] AS [D] 
INNER JOIN dbo.SE_CMSClientMatters AS [mat] 
      ON CAST([mat].[Mcode] AS NVARCHAR(32)) = [D].[custom2]
```

As a general rule, you should *always* try to use the **same datatype** in columns that you use for joining - and joining is typically much easier and faster on **numerical** datatypes, rather than string-based datatypes.

If you could - try to convert one of these two columns to the same datatype as the other - I'm pretty sure that would speed things up significantly.

And also: an index on `Documents` where `Custom2` is at the second position will **NOT** be able to be used for this join - try to create a **separate** index on `custom2` alone:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Documents_custom2 ON dbo.Documents(custom2)
```

Comment: Worked like charm - 28 seconds and done! Thank you so much!